# How do you hack an administrator's account without being caught?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, accounts, administrator, hacking

I am using my school computer but pretty much anything fun i can do on it is blocked, so I want to try to hack the administrator's account so that i can actually have fun on it - without being caught, of course!!

I am using a:
macOS Catalina
Version: 10.15.7
Macbook Air (13-inch, 2017)

Comment: *facepalm* Real hackers do their own research, and there is no shortcut to becoming a real hacker.

Comment: We’re not a place for legal pronouncements, but a warning would make a better answer than a comment. Comments are for clarification and this is very clear. Maybe not advisable, but I think we all can relate to being young and inquisitive. The line between prank and probation depends much more on the school and admin staff than  what is done to a Mac, so a general answer will be the only answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get permission. Then you are helping the administrator - the ways an admin can catch you are so varied, there’s no general way to get around it. They’re always on the lookout for people that are curious and want to learn, so put that energy to good use.

I recommend you find a CTF club or mentor - hack on things that are ethical and wanted until you’re sure of your risk exposure.

- https://dev.to/atan/what-is-ctf-and-how-to-get-started-3f04

Comment: To this I would like to add that you must be sure that the person giving you permission actually has permission to give you permission... i.e. getting permission from a teacher or a local system administrator at your own school might not save yourself from getting into trouble. If something happens and it starts costing money one way or another - then you might find that a regional system administrator team or a school director or similar gets involved and won't accept that kind of permission. Always get it in writing as well.

Answer (score 3):

The phrasing of your question makes this sound like a joke.

In all seriousness, hacking is a criminal offence most places. I would not recommending doing that at all.